# If a stopping time, $T$, satisfies $P(T>k\alpha)\leq (1-\epsilon)^k$ then $E(T)<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, stopping-times

> Suppose that $T$ is a stopping time such that for some positive integer $\alpha$ and some $\epsilon>0$ we have for every $n$:
>   $$
> P(T\leq n+\alpha|\mathcal{F}_n)>\epsilon \text{ a.s.}
> $$

I have shown that for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ and some $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ that $P(T>k\alpha)\leq (1-\epsilon)^k$. I would now like to show that this implies $E(T)<\infty$.

If I let $A_k=\{ T>k\alpha \}$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty P(A_k) < \infty.$ So Borel-Cantelli tells us that $P(A_k \text{ i.o.})=0$. I was hoping to use this to show that $T$ must be bounded above a.s., but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$E[T] = E\bigg[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{T>n\}} \bigg] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T>n) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha P(T>k\alpha)$$ This is a standard trick, and doesn't depend on the fact that $T$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Why is the last inequality true?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : Because $P(T>n)$ is a decreasing function of $n$, so for instance if $\alpha=2$ then the last inequality is just saying that $$P(T>0)+P(T>1)+P(T>2)+P(T>3)+P(T>4)+P(T>5)+...$$$$\le P(T>0)+P(T>0)+P(T>2)+P(T>2)+P(T>4)+P(T>4)+...$$ You can generalize to any $\alpha\in \Bbb N$.